# Feign configuration is not applied in spring boot 3.1.4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

Can you please help me figure out next problem after migration from spring boot 2.7 to 3.1.4 ?
I use next dependency :

```
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.4</version>
```

I have multiply feign clients. These clients work by https .
So I created bean Feign.Builder something like this
pseudocode:

```
    @Bean
    public Feign.Builder feignBuilder() {
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = (hostname, session) -> true;
        return Feign.builder()
                .client(new Client.Default(createSocketFactory(), hostnameVerifier));
    }
```

Next moment is interceptor. I have interceptor

```
public class FooConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor fooInterceptor( {
        ... pseudocode
                return interceptor;
    }

}
```

finally feign client is

```
@FeignClient(name = "foo-client", url = "${foo-client.url}", configuration = FooConfiguration.class)
public interface FooFeignClient {

    @PostMapping("/foo")
    Dto findFoo(@RequestBody FooDto fooDto);
}
```

Problem is interceptor does not work and interceptor was not called. It seems like configuration is not applied when I use client with SSL.

Also, I tested it WITHOUT SSL -when I DONT USE Feign.Builder feignBuilder() it works correctly and interceptor was triggered in SPRING BOOT 3.1.4.

Also I tested it WITH SSL when I USE Feign.Builder feignBuilder() it works correctly and Interceptor was triggered in SPRING BOOT 2.7

Interceptor does not work via feign configuration in spring boot 3.1.4 with SSL.

How can I force an interceptor to work with SSL via feign configuration in spring boot 3.1.4?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and after wasting quite some time on this, I decided to add the header parameter to the function itself like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/send")
void send(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token);
```

I am getting the authToken in the service that is calling the feignClient. It's not ideal, but a workable solution for me right now.